# df.loc to remove whole row based on condition

Tags: python, dataframe

Quick question,

How would I adapt

```
df2.loc[df2['A'] ==0, 'B'] = np.NaN
```

To change to the whole row, aka B,C etc become np.Nan 
Without a for loop as this would take too long

Many thanks

Comment: So everything except column A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want every column including 'A':

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 0, :] = np.NaN
```

If you want every column from 'B' onwards,

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 0, 'B':] = np.NaN
```

More generally, if 'A' isn't the first column:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 0, df.columns.drop('A')] = np.NaN
```

Comment: Thanks that is awesome! Cheers

Comment: Quick Q: 
The dataframe is a time series with columns and an index of date, how would I chage it so it would remove the whole line at certain dates?

Certain meaning the -1/08/2006 and other random days?

Comment: `df.loc['2013-2-23' : '2013-5-22', : ]` or `df.loc['2/23/13' : '5/22/13', : ]` The datetime indexing is pretty smart about understanding what you want.